# Filling a row in a csv file according

Tags: python, csv

Here is a csv file I want to update with python.
It has 3 columns:

```
col1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
col2 = [A, A, A, B, C, C, C, C, A, A] 
col3 = []
```

For each cell in col3 I would like to fill an id number that would change only when the content of col2 changes.

In my example I would get `col3 = [1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4]`

Anyone to show me the way ?

Comment: "only when the content of col2 changes." What do you mean by that? What is the role of `col1`?

Comment: Can you be more precise in your question? Are you asking "How do I fill in the `col3` array?" Or are you asking "How to I write the arrays to a CSV file?"

Comment: Oh, yeah the title is not complete... It should be "Filling a row in a csv file according to the content of another row"

Comment: Tichorama: col1 is useless at the moment =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import csv

with open('f1.csv', newline='') as f_in, open('f2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    for i, (key, group) in enumerate(groupby(reader, key=itemgetter(1)), start=1):
        for row in group:
            writer.writerow(row + [i])
```

If using Python 2.7, change the with-statement to

```
with open('f1.csv', 'rb') as f_in, open('f2.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
```

Comment: Hi Steven, thx for the quick answer..Using the same example csv file i get a "File "C:\path\script.py", line 8, in <module>
    for i, (key, group) in enumerate(groupby(reader, key=itemgetter(1)), start=1):
IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @Kerplouz:  That means you have a blank line in your input file.  Sometimes extra newlines at the end of a file are the source of blank lines.  It's also possible that you have a line with a single item.  You can also get a single item line if your delimiter is not a comma.  For other delimiters do `reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='\t') # or some other delimiter`.

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot, it works perfectly ! Except i forgot to copy the headers... :) But i should be able to manage them. I know it's a dumb/beginner question i asked but i just started learning programming and in the same time i need it for work...

Comment: May i ask why you changed 3 times your script ? :)

Comment: And since i have no manners i would appreciate a commented code with the exact process for each line in the "for loop" ;)

Comment: @Kerplouz:  To copy your headers add before the for-loop: `writer.writerow(next(reader) + ['new_header'])`.  Since this answer works for you, could you click the checkmark next to the answer to mark is as accepted?

Comment: @Kerplouz:  There is a lot happening in the for-statement.  I suggest reading the Python documentation for the imported functions as a complete explanation would be really long.  If you have a specific question I suggest posting as a new question.  If it's a simple question, I might be able to address it in the comments.